# How to randomly change color? Dart and StageXL

Tags: dart, stagexl

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
var shape = new Shape();

shape.graphics.beginPath();
shape.graphics.moveTo(r1.nextInt(1500), r2.nextInt(1500));
shape.graphics.lineTo(r3.nextInt(1500), r4.nextInt(1500));
shape.graphics.strokeColor(Color.Green);
shape.graphics.closePath();
stage.addChild(shape);
 }
```

How can i randomly change the color of the line?

Answer (score 1):

In StageXL, colors are actually just integers. So, as @bp74 says, you can do:

```
var a = 255; // Assuming you want full opacity every time.
var r = random.nextInt(256); // red = 0..255
var g = random.nextInt(256); // green = 0..255
var b = random.nextInt(256); // blue = 0..255
var color = (a << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b;
shape.graphics.strokeColor(color);
```

This is assuming you have `random` defined somewhere above:

```
var random = new Random();
```

Note that you most probably *don't* need several `Random` instances (like you have with `r1`, `r2`, `r3` and `r4`, I assume).

Answer (score 0):

The color in StageXL (and Flash) is a 32 ARGB value. You use 4x8 bit for the alpha, red, green and blue color channel. The following example shows the color 0xFFFFFFFF which is white:

```
var a = 255; // alpha = 0..255
var r = 255; // red = 0..255
var g = 255; // green = 0..255
var b = 255; // blue = 0..255
var color = (a << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b;
```

Comment: So I'll just need to do this? 
'shape.graphics.strokeColor(color);' ? and what Flash? do I need also to install that?

Comment: No you don't need to install Flash! It was just a reference to Flash because StageXL uses the same API as Flash for the most part. A color is just an integer.